# Wanted: A constructive version of a theorem of Furstenberg and Weiss

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients, and let $||\cdot||$ be the distance-from-the-nearest-integer function. It is  known  that for any $ \epsilon > 0 $, the set $S$ of positive integer solutions of the inequality $||f(x)|| < \epsilon$ has bounded gaps. This  means that if $x_1 < x_2  < \ldots$ are the elements of $S$ in increasing order, then the set of differences $x_{n+1}-x_n$ is bounded.  This is proved in   "Simultaneous Diophantine Approximation and IP Sets" by Furstenberg and Weiss, Acta Arith. 1988.

I would like to know how to compute the maximum gap, i.e. the maximum of the values $  x_{n+1}- x_n $, given a specific polynomial and a specific value of $\epsilon$. I can do this for linear polynomials, but not for quadratics. The proof of Furstenberg and Weiss appears to be  non-constructive.

To take a particular example, what is the maximum possible gap between successive solutions of the inequality $||2^{1/2}x^2|| < .01$?  Can anyone suggest a method, no matter how impractical, that would eventually lead to an answer? Could it be that, even in this particular case, no one knows how to find the maximum gap?

Note: Experimentation suggests that the maximum gap is 627, which occurs for the first time following the solution $x=1115714$.

Comment: It's certainly possible to produce a constructive upper bound. Are you really looking for the best possible upper bound?

Comment: I am, because I want to get an (empirical) look at how the gaps depend on $\epsilon$ and on the "diophantine" properties of the coefficients of $f$...... At least a tight upper bound. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I know that the "Heilbronn" problem, ie to see how small ||f(x)|| can be in comparison to x, is in a pretty primitive state. Nevertheless, I'm hoping that there is some way to make Furstenberg's proof constructive.

Comment: OK that gives me a better idea of what you are asking -- enough to see that I don't know the answer I'm afraid. (My gut reaction is that what you're asking for looks hard, but I don't know much about this area so this opinion should not be taken seriously.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dear RJS,

I think Tim Gowers is right - the problem seems too hard. Reasonably good bounds are known on (for example) the *least* $n \geq 1$ for which $\Vert n^2 \sqrt{2} \Vert \leq \epsilon$; one can find such an $n$ with $n \leq \epsilon^{-7/4 + o(1)}$. This is a result of Zaharescu [Zaharescu, A; Small values of $n^2\alpha\pmod 1$. Invent. Math. 121 (1995), no. 2, 379--388.] Zaharescu in fact obtains this result for any $\theta$ in place of $\sqrt{2}$. From a cursory glance at the paper I see that he uses the continued fraction expansion for $\theta$ and so it may be that one can slightly improve his bound in the particular case of $\sqrt{2}$.

It is an old conjecture of Heilbronn that the right bound here should be $\epsilon^{-1 + o(1)}$. I don't know off the top of my head whether any more precise conjectures have been made based on sensible heuristics either for this or for your original problem.

To get *an* explicit upper bound for your problem one can proceed quite straightforwardly using arguments due to Weyl. I don't think this is the right place to describe an argument in detail: there are several variants, and I first learnt this from a Tim Gowers course at Cambridge. See Theorem 3.10 of these notes:

http://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/AdditiveCombinatorics/notes-acnt.pdf

If you really had to show that 627 is the answer to your specific problem, probably the best bet would be to inspect all the quadratics $n^2\sqrt{2} + \theta n + \theta'$ for $\theta,\theta'$ in some rather dense finite subset of $[0,1]^2$ and show using a computer that each takes (mod 1) a value less than 0.009999 for some $n \leq 627$. Painful!

The argument of Furstenberg and Weiss uses ergodic theory and so will not directly lead to an effective bound.

There are quite detailed conjectures about the fractional parts of $n^2\sqrt{2}$ (and other similar sequences) due to Rudnick, Sarnak and Zaharescu, essentially encoding the fact that this sequence of fractional parts is expected to behave like a Poisson process. I don't think those conjectures are likely to be helpful in your context since, taken too literally, they would seem to suggest that there are arbitrarily long intervals without a number such that $\Vert n^2 \sqrt{2} \Vert < 0.01$ - contrary to Furstenberg-Weiss.

Nonetheless let me point out a recent paper of Heath-Brown which is very interesting in connection with these matters:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.0714v1.

One more point perhaps worthy of mention: sequences with bounded gaps are usually known as *syndetic*.

Comment: Thank you for all of these very useful suggestions and references. Your idea about  inspecting the values of $n^2\sqrt{2}+\theta n+\theta'$ for a "very dense mod 1" finite set of pairs $\theta, \theta'$ and for $n \le  627$ seems to lead to a decision procedure, and I can see how a similar idea would work for any polynomial.